# How to deal with obtaining more Force Powers than available?

Tags: powers, star-wars-saga-edition

Because high wisdom is relatively easy to get halfway up the level curve, as is multiple iterations of the Force Training feat; it is quite possible to have a copy of every Force Power ever printed and have slots to spare.

However, something like a wisdom increase may then require me to take a new force power, even if I have them all. As far as I know you are not allowed to take the same power multiple times. How does such a situation resolve?

Comment: Which situation do you mean? One where you need to take a new force power but there are none left to take?

Comment: @doppelspooker Exactly that. I need to take a new force power due to a wisdom increase, but there are none to take.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I've updated the question to help make that explicit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Saga-edition Force Powers are not like a Wizard learning a spell in D&D 3e. It's more like a Wizard *memorizing* a spell in D&D 3e.

As such, when you spend a Force Power, it's gone from your suite of powers until you can take a short rest (though other things can also return powers to your suite). Given all of that, it's no surprise that you can take the same Force Power multiple times. From P96 of the Saga Edition Core Rulebook:

> Don't forget that you can select the same Force power more than once...

This allows you to use it more than once in a single encounter. Obviously, for non-encounter Force Powers like Farseeing, this is not particularly helpful. But for most combat-oriented Powers, it is.

So you can never "run out" of Force Powers to take.

Comment: Missed that quote; guess my question premise was wrong.

Comment: There are also Feats and Talents that have synergies with specific types of Force powers. I can't remember the exact rules, but I had a character who specialized in TK and refreshed all her TK-based powers on a crit (or something like that).